# Adjunct vs complement with intransitive verb

Tags: syntax, english, grammar

Tony came from outside the traditional media

Am I right in thinking because came is intransitive that "outside the traditional media" is an adjunct rather than a subject complement?

Comment: Yes: "came" is here intransitive. I'd say that the PP is a locative complement. "From" serves as a marker of source, where "outside the media" represents the initial location.

Comment: Thanks. So the PP is the subject complement and outside the media is an adjunct?

Comment: No, not a subject complement, just complement of the verb "came". Note that PPs expressing motion (or anything viewed metaphorically as motion) are complements.

Comment: I see, and there is no adjunct?

Comment: No: there's no adjunct. The whole PP "from outside the media" is a complement of "came". So it's subj - verb - complement.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.

Comment: You can tell that the from-phrase is selected for by the verb (and thus a complement rather than an adjunct) in that, when queried for the main predicate in the sentence, you'd probably think of "to come from", with the location specification part of the core  meaning, rather than a bare "to come", which would be a separate lexicon entry with a slightly different semantics of the verb (in the sense of "to arrive").